# How to make d-pointer right in Qt

Tags: qt

I've created the `myClass` class and in order to hide members, used d-pointer but got error while compiling my souce code. Here is the code:

**Header file:**

```
class myClassPrivate;

class myClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~myClass();
    ...
signals:

public slots:

private:
    myClassPrivate *d;
};
```

**and related .cpp**

```
myClass::myClass(QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent),
    d(new myClassPrivate())
{
}

myClass::~myClass()
{
    delete d;
}

class myClassPrivate
{
  public:
    myClassPrivate();
    ...some methods...
    QTextStream stream;
    QFile* m_File;
};

myClassPrivate::myClassPrivate():
    m_File(new QFile)
{
}
```

It says: forward declaration of 'struct myClassPrivate';
         invalid use of incomplete type 'myClassPrivate'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put your `myClassPrivate` declaration before using it in the `myClass` constructor.  In the `.cpp` file:

```
class myClassPrivate
{
    // ...
};

myClass::myClass(QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent),
    d(new myClassPrivate())
{
}
```

You might want to check out some sources on the web explaining the concept and Qt's convenience macros `Q_D`, `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE` and so on:

1. [Blog post on Qt private classes and D-pointers](http://zchydem.enume.net/2010/01/19/qt-howto-private-classes-and-d-pointers/)
2. [KDE Techbase on D-Pointers](http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Library_Code_Policy#D-Pointers)

Comment: Well, thank you and can I create destructor in myClassPrivate in order to release (m_File), or there is no neccessity...

Comment: Yes, you can and *should* create a `~myClassPrivate` destructor `delete`ing the `QFile` -- otherwise you would leak memory!

Answer (score 3):

Check my another answer, there are good sample that can be used as start point: [Invalid use of incomplete type on qt private class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994834/invalid-use-of-incomplete-type-on-qt-private-class/17995691#17995691)